# how to unwrap span of specified class name?

Tags: jquery

I've the following html in desktop browser

```
<div class="mygallery-thumbs">
  <span>
    <img />
  </span>
</div>
```

and the following html in mobile browser

```
<div class="mygallery-thumbs">
  <span>
    <span class="mjwideimg">
       <img />
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

So I need to unwrap `.mjwideimg` but unwrap function doesn't support any parameters. And if I do like the following:

```
//$('.mygallery-thumbs').find('img').unwrap('.mjwideimg');//parameters not supported
$('.mygallery-thumbs').find('img').unwrap();
```

This will produce in desktop browser like this: (which is not okay)

```
<div class="mygallery-thumbs">
    <img />
</div>
```

And will produce in mobile browser like this: (which is okay)

```
    <div class="mygallery-thumbs">
      <span>
        <img />     <-----------------------------------------------------------
      </span>                                                                  |
    </div>                                                                     |
                                                                               |
So I want the output in both browser like mobile browser output. ---------------
```

How can I unwrap `.mjwideimg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('.mygallery-thumbs span.mjwideimg').find('img').unwrap();
```

or you can check if it's on mobile devices then unwrap it:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    $('.mygallery-thumbs').find('img').unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And this is the other way:

```
$('.mygallery-thumbs').find('span.mjwideimg img').unwrap();
//---------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------------find it here to unwrap
```

You can try doing this way:

```
 var myImg = $('.mygallery-thumbs').find('span.mjwideimg').html();
 $('.mygallery-thumbs').find('> span').html(myImg);
```

#### [Demo @ Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LPxjg/)

Answer (score 1):

`$('.mygallery-thumbs span.mjwideimg').find('img').unwrap();`

Comment: So, simple not thought that! Thanks.